# User accounts in Symfony?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony1, user-accounts

I'm new to Symfony. Is my understanding correct that the User class is actually for controlling sessions? But is there built-in login and account creation? I'm not finding it. But if there's an admin backend generator, how can it function without user logins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `myUser.class.php` file is the session controller/storage, yes. You can create your own security module if you wish, but many use the plugins mentioned in [nselikoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526857/user-accounts-in-symfony/2526950#2526950). They're not perfect but they do a decent job. Whichever ORM use, you should definitely start with one of these plugins, and extend/improve them if you need too.

Your admin generator modules are not secured by default, no - it is up to you to implement a security layer. As an aside, don't think of admin-generated modules as exclusively for a backend/backoffice purpose, as there may be some reason for a frontend app to require one. Certainly a system you use internally at your company or at home on a local webserver doesn't need a security layer to function.

Changing the `security.yml` file to secure an app, module or action requires you to specify the login page in your app's `settings.yml`, but the security plugins will help you configure this.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what version of Symfony you're using, but login and account creation is typically incorporated into an application using either the [sfGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin) (for Propel) or [sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) (for Doctrine).

For Symfony v1.2, see [Day 13 of the Jobeet tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/Doctrine/en/13) to get started.

Comment: If I can add is_secure:on to security.yml it will require a login. But the actual login system still has to be created?

Comment: There's a skeleton login form with all the required elements that comes ready. All you need is to customise any HTML/CSS according to your needs. Just follow the instructions in the README file for the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what others have said, I find very useful the source code from symfonians, that resolves all these problems: http://symfonians.org/